# Community - Navigation Menu - Remove or Change home

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, home-page-component, menu

I am trying to delete or change the name of the "home" link in my navigation bar.
Is it possible remove or change name this button without using CSS?

A greeting

[image: Navigation Menu]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Everyone who will need this in most recent version you can add this code in the css to hide the Home in the navigation Menu.

```
.comm-navigation__list > li:first-child { 
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The  answer to this is you will need to create a page variation for the Home page and then you can change the label there .You can assign to all profiles or make that as default.

Answer (score 1):

In combination of both of the prev. comments i have been able to manage this with a good UX.

1. Create new Variation of Homepage with your custom name
2. Make this variation "default"
3. Add custom CSS to hide the default "Home" Tab in Navigation as mentioned above
4. Add new Navigation item, select Home and you can give it a custom name